# How to set low power mode in mac using applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

The new version of macOS introduced low power mode for battery and power adaptor. I am building an app, as a part of I would like to set or unset low power mode using applescript/shell script.

This is what I've written so far which works great where I can get the current status of low power mode whether if it is on or off.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    do shell script "pmset -g | grep lowpowermode"
end tell
```

**After the above step I tried to "set lowpowermode 0" but the script is throwing an error like below**

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    do shell script "set lowpowermode 0"
        --> error number -10004
```

How do I set low power mode to 0 or 1 using applescript/shellscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the Terminal:

```
sudo pmset -a lowpowermode 1
```

Then go to `Apple menu` -> `System Preferences` -> `Battery` and see if it looks good.

---

If that works, I think you'd do it in Applescript something like this:

```
do shell script "pmset -a lowpowermode 1" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: it worked when I added "sudo" Thanks!

Comment: each time I run the script it asks me to confirm the setting with a login password. I wonder if there is a way to ask only once